# Scrolling question list quickly causes vote count text to grow

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app, question-lists

I've found that the vote counts in the question list on the Android app will gradually grow larger in size if I fling the list up and down, forcing it to scroll very quickly. I don't have a truly "scientific" method of describing this insofar as I cannot give you specific scrolling speeds or things of that nature. However, I can consistently reproduce the issue by simply flinging the question list up and down once or twice, with the issue becoming gradually more noticeable if I continue to fling the list back and forth.

To illustrate, here's what the list looks like normally:

[image]

...and here is what it looked like after I flung the list up and down several times in each direction. Notice that not only has all the text for the vote counts gotten larger, but it also appears to have grown to varying degrees (the '0' of the bottom question looks more clipped than the other two, for example):

[image]

Possibly also worth noting is that the answer count doesn't display the same behavior. This is version 0.1.53 of the app on a Nexus 4, running Android 4.3 (CyanogenMod).

Comment: That's... That's... *How does that even happen?!*

Comment: @michaelb958 This is totally a normal failure case for Android ListViews because they reuse list item layouts.  So if you set the list item text size to `textSize+=1` without checking whether its current size is already 24pt, it's easy to create this sort've problem.

Comment: You... you... you flinged a hole in the space-time continuum? Õ_ô

Comment: Happening to me too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eek, that was an ugly bug. Thanks for the report, it's been fixed and will go out in the 0.1.54 updates coming out later tonight.